# Set a selector for "setDoubleAction" through "Interface Builder"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, interface-builder

Is it possible to set a selector for "setDoubleAction" through  "Interface Builder" or it can only be done by "XCode"?

If it can be done only by "XCode" I would like to know why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IB, you set the target and single-click action at the same time. There is no way to separately set the double-click action.

You can set it using a Binding, providing you can get to the intended target that way, but this is a bit like swatting a fly with a hydraulic hammer.

The easiest way is just to set it in code.

(What editor you use has nothing to do with it.)

Comment: Well, when I said "XCode" in fact I wanted to say "Programmatically". If is so difficult to work with "Events" with the Apple tools for development then this make me a little frustrated. Tools like Delphi and even the NetBeans has easy solutions to deal with Events in the GUI, that is why I'm trying to figure out how is the way to go through "Interface Builder".
Is that, the way to go is "Programmatically", no easy way like: select some event then select a callback?

Comment: Target-action is at a higher level than events. IB works at the target-action level. The view is going to handle the event; it will translate it into an action message to the target for you. Setting the double-click action is one line of code; it's not like you have to, say, implement an entire event handler method or something.

Comment: One more question: Why the Events appear on the inspector if it is not possible connect to they? They have another utility? (Thanks)

Comment: Actions are not events. The Inspector lists actions because you can hook up to them—for the single-click action. (Note that a table view is a kind of control, so it can, in fact, send an action on every single click.)

Comment: Sorry, I  am having difficulties to say what I want. I want to say the actions like: doClick; doDoubleClick; performClick; selectAll; etc...

Comment: Right. Interface Builder lets you set the table view's single-click action to one of those (just as with any other control), but it does not provide a way to set the double-click action.